# convert html code into xaml for RichTextBox in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-3.0

how can I format this html code:

```
<p>For the iPhone do the following:
<ul>
<li>Go to AppStore</li>
<li>Search by M&#229lApp</li>
<li>Download</li></ul>
</p><p>
Android To do this:
<ul>
<li>Go to the Market</li>
<li>Search by M&#229lApp</li>
<li>Download</li>
</ul>
</p>
```

into XAML for RichTextBox in Windows Phone?

**Update**

so in result it should be:

For the iPhone do the following:

- Go to AppStore
- Search by MålApp
- Download

Android To do this:

- Go to the Market
- Search by MålApp
- Download

Comment: Why not just use the WebBrowser control?

Comment: because it doesn't have scrolling

Comment: Does HttpUtility.HtmlDecode available for WP7? If so I think it could be helpfull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you can Replace < li > tags with & # 8226 ;

See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach is to verify the html as valid and then walk the content converting to the XAML equivalent.

There are [lots of examples of attempting this online](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=convert%20xaml%20to%20html)

It is far more performant to do such a conversion on a server and pull the formatted version to the phone and then display with [XamlReader.Load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190359%28v=vs.95%29).

**Update**
For each element in the HTML you'll just be adding a new TextBlock to a container (probably a `StackPanel`) and for the `<li>` items you'll just want to prefix with a symbol to represent the bullet and adjust the left margin appropriately. You'll probably benefit from defining appropriate styles and then just applying the appropriate style for the element you're converting.

Comment: thanks, but in my question I want to know how to convert <ul><li></ul> in xaml

Comment: @revolutionkpi it will totally depend on what you want the output to look like